# Opening Word docs in Sharepoint 2013 not in Word

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I would like to open my Word documents in the browser and not in the program Word. I have Office 2013, I don't know if this matters. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office Web Apps are optional in SharePoint 2013 installations. Assuming on-premises (not Office 365), your installation may not have Office Web Apps installed or configured correctly (e. g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ff431687.aspx).

For Office 365 it depends on the subscription level.

Comment: i don't use Office 365, I have Office 2013 installed on all the clients. Thanks will read this thread you posted. !

Comment: Dear Mike
I'm in the Sharepoint 2013 Management Shell tring to change the SPWOPIBinding. i entered new-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName ins.w2k -AllowHTTP now i get an error : sorry, we have encountered an error and .... has failed.

Comment: My Servername was incorrect i corrected this , now i get another error : You are not authorized to connect to ins-shp2013. binding has been cancelled.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know off the top of my head the rights needed to set up the binding. You are the right track though.

Comment: Oke thanks for the information Mike ! i will search a bit more to find the right i need to set these bindings.